# Erlang - Won't gen_tcp:send work when trying to get Google's web page?

Tags: sockets, erlang

I was reading Programming with Sockets in Armstrong's 'Software for a Concurrent World book' and tried to work out an example on making a connection to Google website and getting the page content,

```
connect(Url) ->
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Url,80,[binary,{packet,0}]),
ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"),
receive_msg(Socket, []).
```

I thought this was because Google used https and so I checked with other websites that used http and this time I got 403 Forbidden Error.

Currently wont this code work?

Comment: Works fine for me. What is `Url` set to? It should be just a hostname, not a full `http://...` URL.

Comment: How do you like that book (the new version I assume)?

Comment: Also consider using `httpc` as in provides higher level abstraction

Comment: @SteveVinoski I got 302 for www.google.com and the body was that the page has been moved. For any other websites I am getting 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: @7stud I am using the first edition.

Comment: @Lol4t0 I am just testing with the basic stuff but will look into using httpc :)